# I'm writing a browser extension I need to create windows with which the user can interact for extension work. what should I use?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, devtools

I'm writing a browser extension for extracting data from web pages and I need to create some windows that you can navigate through and so that they exist when moving to another web page of the same domain.

I tried to use dynamic creation of windows in pure js and introducing them into the dom; it’s not particularly clear how to save the window and its state when moving to other pages. I know about popup, dev tools but i don't know what i better should use

Comment: You can save the state in `chrome.storage`. See also [sidePanel API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel).